# How to tune Vim Perl 6 syntax highlighting to de-emphasize sigils?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, raku

I'm using [vim-perl6](https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl6) for syntax highlighting, but I'd like to adjust the color of variable sigils so that they are less standout. Perhaps, make them look pale or something. How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: A vim syntax file will typically just identify different parts of the language syntax (eg, `Keyword`, `Number`, `Constant`, or for variables, probably `Identifier`). It is then the job of your colorscheme file to color those different things... So you probably want to change something in your colorscheme file, not in the vim-perl6's syntax file.

Comment: You'll need a modified (or additional) syntax file as well, since `perl6.vim` links `p6BareSigil` to `p6Variable`, which itself is linked to `Identifer`. You'll want to undo the link of `p6BareSigil` so that your colorscheme can colorscheme can color it specifically, or link it to something appropriate that your color scheme already colors the way you want.

Comment: Just tried out @chepner 's suggestion, and it seems to do what I want now. Here's what I did: 1) comment out the line: `HiLink p6Variable Identifier` in `perl6.vim` 2) Modify the colorscheme file I use, and add `hi p6Variable ctermfg=darkgrey` and `hi p6Variable guifg=darkgrey` Thanks!

Comment: @cowbaymoo You should post that as an answer; it is allowed (even encouraged!) to provide an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 4):

1. Comment out the line: `HiLink p6Variable Identifier` in `perl6.vim`
2. Modify the colorscheme file I use (in my case, on MacOS, I copied it from `/usr/share/vim/vim80/colors/` to `~/.vimrc/colors/`), and add to it:

   - `hi p6Variable ctermfg=darkgrey`
   - `hi p6Variable guifg=darkgrey`